# How do I replace column names with values in a row

Tags: python, pandas

How do I replace column names with the values in the 4th row, i.e row index 3

Answer (score 0):

You can assign column names to your desired row number:

```
index = 3
df.columns = df.iloc[index]
```

if you want to use the dataframe index use `loc` instead:

```
df.columns = df.loc[index]
```